# Silverlight: webcam not getting activated when deployed on live server

Tags: silverlight

My silverlight page has the following code:

```
public camera()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        cs.CaptureImageCompleted += new EventHandler<CaptureImageCompletedEventArgs>(cs_CaptureImageCompleted);
        VideoBrush vBrush = new VideoBrush();
        vBrush.SetSource(cs);
        vBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        Cam.Fill = vBrush;
        if (CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess())
        {
            cs.Start();
        }
}
```

This code works fine when I run the website from within visual studio. However, once I deploy the website and run it on internet explorer I don't even get asked permission to turn the webcam on.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturedeviceconfiguration.requestdeviceaccess(v=vs.95).aspx):

> Calling RequestDeviceAccess should be done from the context of a
>   user-initiated event. If a call is made that is not from a
>   user-initiated context, no exception is thrown. However, the dialog is
>   not displayed in this case. The RequestDeviceAccess return value will
>   still return results of any previously granted access request or other
>   condition in this case, but otherwise the call is a no-op.

Thus, you can't call CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess() on your class constructor, but should call it from an user event, like a button click.

You probably called it from a user-initiated event before, while you tested within visual studio. I believe that after you moved your code to a constructor, and then the method returned true because of its previously granted access. But when you published your website, the browser, since you're accessing a different domain, your application doesn't have granted access. That's why it works within visual studio, but not on live server.